# robots.txt file being overridden / injected from external source?

Tags: wordpress, robots.txt

We have a couple of Wordpress sites with this same issue.  They appear to have a "robots.txt" file with the following contents:

```
User-Agent: *
Crawl-Delay: 300
User-Agent: MJ12bot
Disallow: /
User-agent: MegaIndex.ru
Disallow: /
User-agent: megaindex.com
Disallow: /
```

We have absolutely no idea where this robots.txt file is coming from.

We have looked and there is definitely no "robots.txt" file in the public_html root folder or any sub-folder that we can see.

We have deactivated every single plugin on the site and even changed themes, but the robots.txt file remains exactly the same.  It seems as though it is somehow being injected into the site from an external source somehow!

We have been assured that it couldn't be coming from Google Tag Manager.

Just wondering if anyone happens to recognise the above robots.txt contents and knows how it is existing on our sites???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a generic robots.txt file that our server administrator had set up to be injected into every site on our server to prevent our server being attacked and overloaded by those particular bots (which we had been having trouble with).

Answer (score 0):

You have a few possibilities.

Some security plugins (WordFence, iTheme etc) actually add files to your site. These files don't generally go away when you just "disable" the plugins. They need to be actually removed/uninstalled and sometimes you have to manually go through and do it.

WordPress will generate a virtual robots.txt.

If Google has cached that. You can go in and tell Google to look at the robots.txt again.

You should also be able to overwrite it by creating your own by just making a robots.txt file and putting it in the root or using another plugin to do it.